# Filter bar has styling issues

Tags: bug, design

Since the updated UI to the site there seems to be a styling issue with the filter bar where the filter is overlapping the *Featured On Meta* bulletin as seen in the image below. The styling issue occurs whilst screen is in Portrait Orientation

[image]

Comment: agreed [Not pritty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api%20or%20google-analytics%20or%20google-analytics-api%20or%20gmail-api%20or%20google-drive-sdk%20or%20youtube-api%20or%20google-plus%20or%20or%20google-oauth%20or%20gmail%20or%20oauth%20or%20google-api-dotnet-client%20or%20google-api-php-client%20or%20google-compute-engine%20or%20google-calendar%20)  it would be nice if we could remove this box all together or set the font size smaller.

Comment: @DaImTo Definitely not pretty. Another possibility is to have this box added to the new bar on the left

Comment: yeah or just a little arrow so that we can hide it if we choose.